# Is it possible to find a norm on the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n \geq 1$.

> Is it possible to find a norm on $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$? (If not, why?).

Where a norm $\rho$ is a function $\rho: \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \to \mathbb{R}$, having the following properties:
$\forall c \in \mathbb{C}, u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$,

(1) $\rho(v) \geq 0$. $\rho(v)=0$ if and only if $v=0$

(2) $\rho(cv)= |c|\rho(v)$

(3) $\rho(u+v) \leq \rho(u)+\rho(v)$

Any comments are welcome!

I have a problem with the second property, which ruins some ideas I had in mind.

Comment: There certainly is a norm on this ring given your conditions. I don't know if there's a nice, clean one, but one *does* exist.

Comment: @MattSamuel, thanks!! But how do you know that? Is there an existence theorem that I am missing?

Comment: Wouldn't​ the norm of the coefficient treated as a vector work?

Comment: @Jean Yeah, you could take the square root of the sum of squared absolute values of the coefficients. That should work.

Comment: But what about $n \geq 2$?

Comment: For example, when $n=2$, write $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. How to define the norm of $u=\sum_{i=0}^{m}u_iy^i$, $u_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: There is no norm which makes it into a Banach space, though. This is a nice exercise with the Baire category theorem, if I'm remembering right.

Comment: For example, when $n=2$, write $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. How to define the norm of $u=\sum_{i=0}^{m}u_iy^i$, $u_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Perhaps define it to be the norm of $u_m$?

Comment: @AreaMan, its completion is $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$? And, please, can you elaborate on the existence of a norm?

Comment: Consider the polynomials as functions on the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or for symmetry, on the complex [polydisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydisc). Then take any functional norm on the space of functions, e.g. the sup norm. It will induce a norm on the subset of polynomials. It will not be complete in it, of course, for $n=1$ the completion gives you all holomorphic functions. For other norms of this sort see [Bergman spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergman_space). Alternatively, take a norm of the vector of coefficients of monomials $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$.

Comment: @Conifold, thanks! Did you mean in your second option, that, for example, the norm of $i+x+2y-xy+x^3$ is the norm of $(i,1,2,0,-1,0,3)$ as an element of $\mathbb{C}^7$? (You can post your comment as an answer, if you like).

Comment: Not quite $\mathbb{C}^7$ since you want to push *all* polynomials into a single space. So potentially you have unbounded number of coefficients, although always finitely many non-zero ones. You can take $\sup$ of them all, or the square root of the sum of squares, for polynomials this is always defined. Restricted to polynomials with only those seven monomials non-zero it will give you a norm on  $\mathbb{C}^7$.

Comment: Thanks. Truly, I meant $(i,1,2,0,-1,0,3,0,0,0,\ldots)$, but for computation I think of it as an element of $\mathbb{C}^7$. Please, can you explain the non-completeness when $n\geq 2$?

Comment: Obviously, some vectors with infinitely many non-zero coefficients will be in the completion (it is the same even for $n=1$).

Comment: ok, so this is what I have thought and mentioned above, that the completion is $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$. Thanks for your confirmation and other comments.

Comment: No, it is not $\mathbb{C}[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$. That one includes *all* infinite vectors of coefficients, not just some. The completion is much smaller, and depends on the choice of a norm.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me; so I do not understand how the completion looks like. I thought that an infinite sequence with infinite non-zero components could serve as an element of the completion. (I am sorry for taking your time with all my questions).

Comment: Understanding it requires much more familiarity with [Banach spaces of sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space), it is not a topic for a comment thread.

Comment: ok, I agree, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial structure is a red herring; you only care about its vector space structure, and $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is a complex vector space of *countable* dimension.

Another description of this space is that it is the vector space of all complex sequences that have only finitely many nonzero terms.

As an example, any of the $L^p$ norms would work: for real $p \geq 1$

$$ \| \vec{a} \|_p = \left( \sum_{n} | a_n |^p \right)^{1/p} $$

defines a norm, as does,

$$ \| \vec{a} \|_{\infty} = \max_n\left( |a_n| \right) $$

Basically the same description works to define these norms on polynomials directly, rather than the alternate representation in terms of sequences: just take the sums over the coefficients of the polynomial rather than terms of a sequence.

Comment: Thanks! Please, how one shows that $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is not complete in each of those norms?

Comment: @user237522 with this norm $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ with its $L^p$ norm. Thus this normed vector space is complete.

Comment: @Bryan No, it isn't. $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is infinite-dimensional since it contains all polynomials in $n$ variables. You are confusing the number of variables with dimension.

Comment: @user237522 You can use the Baire category theorem to show that any infinite Banach space must have uncountably infinite dimension. Otherwise, let $\{a_1, \ldots \}$ be a basis. Let $V_n$ be the span of the first n basis vectors. Then each $V_n^c$ is dense and open. If the space was complete, the intersection all of the $V_n^c$ would be dense by the Baire category theorem. However, you can easily see that this intersection is empty, since every vector (which is a finite linear combination of the $a_i$, we are talking basis as a vector space) must lie in some $V_n$.

Comment: @Conifold Are we talking about $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ for a fixed $n$ or $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$? The OP doesn't make any remark claiming that a polynomial of arbitrarily large strings of variables may occur.

Comment: @Bryan $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#The_polynomial_ring) for any field $K$. Already $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is infinite-dimensional since it contains arbitrarily high powers of $x$.